# How to debug Chainlink job task?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

We are trying to call an API(Deployed on my machine using ngrok for testing) from Chainlink. We are following the tutorial at https://docs.chain.link/docs/advanced-tutorial/ and using Rinkeby network. The only things we have changed are job id, oracle id and API URL which returns a simple json.
We can see the transaction happening and even a fee of 0.1 LINK is deducted.
But the API is not called(We know this because I can see the realtime logs of the API) and hence the response value is also not fetched in smart contract.

How to debug this? Is there a way to check logs of the job?

Below is my contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.6;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.7/ChainlinkClient.sol";

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT WHICH USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */
contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
  
    uint256 public temperature;
    
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    
    constructor () {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oracle = 0x46cC5EbBe7DA04b45C0e40c061eD2beD20ca7755;
        jobId = "60803b12c6de4443a99a6078aa59ef79";
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; // 0.1 LINK (Varies by network and job)
    }
    
    function requestVolumeData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) 
    {
        Chainlink.Request memory request = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);        
        request.add("get", "http://my-api.com");
        request.add("path", "temperature");

        // Multiply the result by 1000000000000000000 to remove decimals
        // int timesAmount = 10**18;
        // request.addInt("times", timesAmount);
        // Sends the request
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, request, fee);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive the response in the form of int
     */ 
    function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _temperature) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        temperature = _temperature;
    }
    // function withdrawLink() external {} - Implement a withdraw function to avoid locking your LINK in the contract
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started debugging chainlink jobs is to look into the logs. There are 2 main ways to look into the logs.

1. If running in a docker container:

Run this command to find the name of the docker container.

```
docker ps
```

Then

```
docker logs <NAME_OF_DOCKER_CONTAINER>
```

2. Read the `log.jsonl` file.
   If you created this in your `.chainlink-rinkeby` folder, it'll be in `.chainlink-rinkeby/log.jsonl`

Otherwise you can read the `JSON` of the job that you're debugging.

[image]